# Office.js issue with fetching “to” field of a message in Outlook for Mac 16.18 (181014)

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

I’m working on an add-in for Microsoft Outlook, and I’ve noticed that in the latest version of Outlook for Mac, 16.18 (181014), our add-in is unable to retrieve recipients of a draft that’s just been created.  Our add-in is attempting to fetch the recipients using office.js’s `Office.context.mailbox.item.to.getAsync()` method.  To reproduce this issue:

1. While reading an email in your inbox, click the “reply” button to begin drafting a new email; the new draft should automatically have a recipient in the “to” field because it is a reply.
2. From this draft, open an add-in which will try to fetch the draft’s “to” recipients by calling `Office.context.mailbox.item.to.getAsync()`.  No recipients will be found.
3. In the “to” field of the draft, add an additional recipient, and
   then remove this recipient.
4. Try to fetch the recipient from your
   add-in again by calling `Office.context.mailbox.item.to.getAsync()` -
   this time you will be given the “to” recipients correctly.

We’ve only noticed this issue in version 16.18 (181014).  It appears that the user must manually edit the “to” field before the `getAsync()` method is able to give us its contents.

Comment: Curious if you tried saving the message first using Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync to see if it allows you to get the "to" field after that.

Comment: I've been testing this with the `saveAsync()` call, and it turns out that this is not fixing the issue for us in Outlook for Mac; it also has made it so that we cannot detect recipients in Outlook 2016 for Windows and the Outlook Web App.

Could there be an issue with the way Outlook for Mac returns the recipients array to us with the `item.to.getAsync()` method?

Comment: This issue has been fixed, request you to please update to the latest Insider build.